# closed loop pole of negative feedback

Tags: closed-loop

given w be the pole of open loop what in the pole of the closed lop shown bellow?
i have found axpression for GAIN but for the pole i am not sure.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Is the diagram part of the original question?

Comment: Yes, it shown negative feedback system
I need to know what is the pole in closed loop

Comment: is the pole within the `a` or the `f` ? If it is in the `a` is `f` a constant number ? Can `a` be written in the form \$\frac{k}{s+w}\$ ?

Comment: You need to show the complete question in its original form. Currently there’s not enough information.

Comment: Hello i just need a formula of closed loop pole Vs open loop pole  in a single pole system.

Comment: You already have it. \$\frac{a}{1+af}\$. If you know how to write `a` in terms of the pole `w`, just plug it in to the formula.

Answer (score 0):

The forward path TF, including a pole, is
$$\small G_1 (s)=\frac{a}{(1+\tau s)}=\frac{a/\tau}{s+1/\tau}=\frac{a/\tau}{s+\omega_{B1}}$$

where \$\small \omega_{B1}\$ is the bandwidth.

Thus, the pole is at \$\small s=-1/\tau =-\omega_{B1}\$, the DC gain is \$a\$, and the gain-bandwidth product, is $$\small GBW= \frac{a}{\tau}$$

The closed loop TF is: $$\small G_2 (s)=\frac{a/\tau}{s+(1 +af)/\tau}=\frac{a/\tau}{s+\omega_{B2}}$$

Hence, the pole has moved to \$\small s=-(1 +af)/\tau=-\omega_{B2}\$, and the bandwidth has increased by a factor, \$\small (1+af)\$.

the DC gain is now: \$\small a/(1+af)\$, so the gain-bandwidth product remains at: \$\small GBW=\large \frac{a}{\tau}\$, as, of course, it must.